# How to get current location on android

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager

Hey guys 
i want to get the latitude and longitude of the users location.
I have tried developers site and stack overflow , there are loads of examples targeted on the moving user which use some thing like :-
onLocationChanged() 
I dont need updates of the location , the user will just open it for a minute or two 
so i need to find the location the time the application starts and what if the user has never used any geolocation app before hence i would also like an alternative for
LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()

My code is :-

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // connect to the GPS location service
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Toast.makeText(currentLocation.this, "Latitude -> "+Double.toString(loc.getLatitude())
                +" Longitude is -> "+Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and is working fine.
But i am scared that the getLastKnownLocation may return null when used for first time.

Thanks

Comment: You've asked 9 questions and have never accepted an answer.  Accept correct answers to your previous questions and more users will pay attention to your new questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sign up for location updates and once you receive the first update, you can unregister for future updates.

In other words, create a `LocationListener` and register it with your `LocationManager`'s `requestLocationUpdates` method. In the `onLocationChanged` method of your `LocationListener`, call the `removeUpdates` method on your `LocationManager`, with `this` as parameter.

It might take some time before you get a new location, but except for using `getLastKnownLocation` there's not really an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But requestLocationUpdates has 4 parameters, third one being the minimum distance it travels for the callback to occur and dats what i am confused should i drop in null over there? since may be the user is not moving....

Comment: Passing 0 as the minDistance will make sure the method is called each time a new location is received.